# Apt install package but without source files

Tags: apt, package-management

These are what I type:

```
apt install libkrb5-dev
```

After installed successful, I can't find "/usr/include/gssapi.h", which expected installed on last command.

```
# apt-file list libkrb5-dev
libkrb5-dev: /usr/bin/krb5-config
libkrb5-dev: /usr/include/gssapi.h
libkrb5-dev: /usr/include/gssapi/gssapi.h
libkrb5-dev: /usr/include/gssapi/gssapi_ext.h
# locate gssapi.h
#
```

I was using ubuntu 18.10 cosmic and package files list is [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libkrb5-dev/filelist).

Who can tell me why headers file is not installed? And more How to fix it?

Thx.

---

```
root@zfs-gitlab-ci:~# ls /usr/include
aio.h        c++        endian.h    fmtmsg.h   gnu-versions.h  kdb.h       locale.h    mtd        netpacket   proc_service.h  reglib       shadow.h       string.h       tgmath.h     utmp.h            xfs
aliases.h    com_err.h  envz.h      fnmatch.h  grp.h           krb5        malloc.h    net        netrom      profile.h       resolv.h     signal.h       strings.h      thread_db.h  utmpx.h
alloca.h     complex.h  err.h       fstab.h    gshadow.h       krb5.h      math.h      netash     netrose     protocols       rpc          sound          stropts.h      threads.h    values.h
argp.h       cpio.h     errno.h     fts.h      gssapi          langinfo.h  mcheck.h    netatalk   nfs         pthread.h       rpcsvc       spawn.h        sudo_plugin.h  time.h       video
argz.h       crypt.h    error.h     ftw.h      gssapi.h        lastlog.h   memory.h    netax25    nl_types.h  pty.h           sched.h      stab.h         syscall.h      ttyent.h     wait.h
ar.h         ctype.h    et          gawkapi.h  gssrpc          libgen.h    misc        netdb.h    nss.h       pwd.h           scsi         stdc-predef.h  sysexits.h     uchar.h      wchar.h
arpa         dirent.h   execinfo.h  gconv.h    iconv.h         libintl.h   mit-krb5    neteconet  obstack.h   rdma            search.h     stdint.h       syslog.h       ucontext.h   wctype.h
asm-generic  dlfcn.h    fcntl.h     getopt.h   ifaddrs.h       limits.h    mntent.h    netinet    paths.h     re_comp.h       semaphore.h  stdio_ext.h    tar.h          ulimit.h     wordexp.h
assert.h     drm        features.h  glob.h     inttypes.h      link.h      monetary.h  netipx     poll.h      regex.h         setjmp.h     stdio.h        termio.h       unistd.h     x86_64-linux-gnu
byteswap.h   elf.h      fenv.h      gnumake.h  kadm5           linux       mqueue.h    netiucv    printf.h    regexp.h        sgtty.h      stdlib.h       termios.h      utime.h      xen
```

Comment: what does `ls /usr/include/` display?

Comment: @singrium directory exist.

Comment: As I can see, the file exists 'gssapi.h' too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`locate` is not a real-time search, but uses a file database that gets updated automatically once per day. Therefore it will not display any files that you just installed moments ago.

You can manually update `locate`'s database using:

```
sudo updatedb
```

After you ran that, `locate` should know about all existing files at that point and correctly display the newly installed files.

Other than that, you can use other tools like `ls /usr/include/gssapi.h` to check if that file is existing.

Comment: `once per day` Which configuration file can be edited to change that? I don't see any folder `/etc/locate...`?

Comment: That would be a different question... though I think it'll be answered somewhere in here: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=locate

Comment: @cat It's invoked by `cron` once per day, because it has a script in `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` that runs the `updatedb` command (in a special way that makes sure it doesn't stress the system much). You could e.g. move that script from `/etc/cron.daily` to `/etc/cron.hourly` to increase the interval, or add a custom `crontab` entry for it.